# I have setup apache server, how to reset root password?

Tags: apache, sql-server-2005, ssh

I have finished setting up apache on Ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to ssh to it (ssh root@localhost). It asks me for a password. I don't remember setting up any password! How can I ssh it for the first time?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/OS tech support.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `ssh root@localhost` will attempt to log into the local root user on the machine you run the command on - via [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

It might be wiser to use `sudo su` instead to directly log in as root instead of the current user since connecting to localhost with SSH seems unnecessary in this case.

By default, the root password is not set. Assuming that you have sudo privileges, you can set one with `sudo passwd root`.

If you decide that you actually need to use SSH (instead of simply logging into the root account with `su`) you will find hopefully the answers here useful:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04

Good luck!

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks for this!  I didn't realize that the password was never set, which is why I could never access root.